# How to add product manufacturer detail in checkout page oscommerce

Tags: checkout, oscommerce

I am searching to display `product manufacturer detail` in `checkout page` for `Oscommerce`.

Anyone can help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your issue is very easily solved if you have even a basic understanding of PHP, MySQL, and osCommerce structure. My understanding of stackoverflow is that it's a place to get help after you've tried to solve the problem yourself but are stuck.  Please amend your question with what you have tried and where specifically you are stuck.  If you cannot do that then you should just hire a programmer to do this for you.  It's incredibly easy to make your change and wouldn't cost your much.

Comment: i have tired some solution but still struggle to get, so only i post my question in stackoverflow. finally i got solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution friends, go to /includes/classes/order.php, in that file check below line 
'id' => $products[$i]['id']);

replace with

'id' => $products[$i]['id'],
'manufacturer' => $products[$i]['manufacturer']);

then add $order->products[$i]['manufacturer'] in checkout.php file or any where in checkout file